# Regulare expression for finding words started with @ and end with whitespaces or new line

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a Java regex to find usernames in a text.

Usernames always start with `@`. No whitespace is acceptable after `@`.  Usernames are combinations of upper- or lowercase letters, digits, `.`, `_`, `-`.

So, the regex should match words that start with `@` and end with whitespace or newline.

For example, the text `hi @anyOne.2 I'm looking for @Name_13
@name14 @_n.a.m.e-15 but not @ name16` contains the following matches: `anyOne.2`, `Name_13`, `name14`, `_n.a.m.e-15`.

I am using

```
String pattern = "@[^\\s]*(\\w+)";
```

Comment: I think you need `(?<=\B@)\S+`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6AsTP6/1)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
\B@(\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6AsTP6/2).

**Details**

- `\B` - a non-word boundary, the char that is right before the current location must be a non-word char (or start of string)
- `@` - a `@` char
- `(\S+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more non-whitespace characters.

See [Java sample usage](https://ideone.com/jDA8e6):

```
String text = "hi @anyOne.2 I'm looking for @Name_13 @name14 @_n.a.m.e-15 but not @ name16";
String pattern = "\\B@(\\S+)";
// Java 9+
String[] results = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(text).results().flatMap(grps -> Stream.of(grps.group(1))).toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results)); // => [anyOne.2, Name_13, name14, _n.a.m.e-15]

// Java 8 (include import java.util.stream.*)
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(text);
List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) {
    strs.add(m.group(1));
}
System.out.println(strs); // => [anyOne.2, Name_13, name14, _n.a.m.e-15]
```